# Take someone's word for it

Tags: sentence-meaning

This sentence:

> I took his word for it.

I know the meaning of the sentence:

> I believed what he said was true.

My question is "why". Or, in other words, how to interpret this grammatically, especially the part **"for it"**. How does the preposition "for" work here? What does "it" mean?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I took his word **for it.**

**It** refers to whatever the situation is/was/. You have not told us what it is so we cannot specifically say what it refers to in your question.

Here is an example of the usage:

When he told me he had not stolen the cake, I took his word for it.

it= telling me he did not steal the cake.

> - The **it** pronoun refers back to any particular situation in a context.
>
> Would you take my word for that statement?  Would you take my word for
>   it?

Comment: To add to this: in this expression, "took" means "accepted (e.g. as evidence or proof)". So when I say "I'll take your word for it" I mean that I'll accept your statement or your promise (your "word") as sufficient proof. Therefore I don't need to question or investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comment. So basically does "it" mean some statement made by someone, and "take one's word for it" mean "take one's word as a proof for the statement?

Comment: You **take someone's word for what your interlocutor or another person said previously about something**. Yes, the **it** refers to the other person's words, exactly.

Comment: Alright. Everything is clear. Thanks!